# leading spaces in lines following i command are trimmed

Tags: sed

I'm trying to add a line in a file at a specific line :

```
sed -i.bak '2i\
  test\
' /tmp/hosts.yaml
```

My problem is that the inserted line in the file doesn't have the 2 spaces.
How can i keep the 2 spaces ?

Thanks

Comment: Write `test` with spaces to a file. Use `r` sed command. Does `'2i     test'` would work? (why the "\" ?)

Comment: @KamilCuk `i` without ``\`` is a GNU extension. POSIX sed only knows about ``i\``.

Comment: '2i test' gives me : sed: 1: "2i test": command i expects \ followed by text

Comment: You have this tagged linux, but don't seem to be using the GNU sed that's normal with that OS... (I get the spaces with it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this behavior on OmniOS' sed (couldn't find an explanation in the man page though), and backslashing leading spaces worked there. E.g.:

```
sed -i.bak '2i\
\ \ test\
' /tmp/hosts.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit a file in a script, I find that `ed` works a lot better than the non-standard `sed -i` (Not the least because it's intended from the start for working with files, not individual lines in a stream, which makes more complicated things a lot easier):

```
$ cat foo.txt                                  
- line 1
- line 2
- line 3
$ printf "%s\n" 2i "  test" "" . w | ed -s foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt                                     
- line 1
  test

- line 2
- line 3
```

Or in heredoc form, which is usually easier to read:

```
ed -s foo.txt <<EOF
2i
  test

.
w
EOF
```